# Function Redefinition of the Same Pattern for Every Argument Type

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I had to synchronize a thread-unsafe output function so that it doesn't crash when multiple threads try to interact with the standard output at the same time. I have done some C, but I am quite new to C++ programming. In C there aren't usually that much generic functions, but in C++ I can see one method or overloaded operator having even ten or more versions with different argument types.

In my program below I locked operator<< of QTextStream by making another function print() calling QTextStream::operator<<. I would like to change my code that whenever I call QTextStream::operator<<, it is automatically the mutex locked version. How can this be done?

Also, one little subquestion is that why doesn't my code work when I put the QMutex global variable in as a local variable of print()?

```
QTextStream qout(stdout);
QMutex mutex;

template<typename T>
void print(T t)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    qout << t << flush;
}

class my_thread : public QThread
{
public:
    int n;

    my_thread()
    {
        n = 0;
    }

    void run()
    {
        while(n < 10)
        {
            print(n++);
            msleep(500);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    enum { N_THREADS = 10 };
    std::array<my_thread, N_THREADS> thread_array;
    for (auto& thread : thread_array)
    {
        thread.start();
    }
    for (auto& thread : thread_array)
    {
        thread.wait();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Write your own QTextStream with locking support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (not tested)?

```
class LockedTextStream {
private:
  QMutex mutex;
  QTextStream textStream;

public:
  template <class... Args>
  LockedTextStream(Args&&... args) : textStream(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

  template <class T>
  LockedTextStream& operator<<(const T& t) {
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    textStream << t;
    return *this;
  }
};

LockedTextStream sharedStream(stdout);

...
    sharedStream << n++;
....
```

This wrapper should take any constructor arguments and forward them to QTextStream, and should lock any call to operator<<().

The reason QMutex can't be a local variable inside a function is that then the mutex is allocated in the context of that function.  The whole point of a mutex is that you are operating on the *same* mutex in every thread.